# Request Format from Javascript to Postman

Tags: javascript, rest, postman

For start, I am new to programming, so not realy sure how to ask this correctly.

I am working on an integration between my company's pbx and a external CRM. I have the CRM documentation (that is really laking) and it presents the request in this format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    .callMethod(
        "crm.lead.list", 
            { 
                order: { "STATUS_ID": "ASC" },
                filter: { ">OPPORTUNITY": 0, "!STATUS_ID": "CONVERTED" },
                select: [ "ID", "TITLE", "STATUS_ID", "OPPORTUNITY", "CURRENCY_ID" ]
            }
```

How do I set a request on the format used by Postman to try some queries?

I tried /crm.lead.list?$filter={"PHONE":"333444"} and several variations on that, but can't make it work. It always bring me the full lead list and ignores the filters.

Comment: There's no possible way we could know as we do not know what the `callMethod` function is doing. For a start, we would need to know what CRM you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

/crm.lead.list?filter[PHONE]=333444